# how to create/add model object to a database model of a selected type of user in the registration form

Tags: django

how to create/add model object to a database model of a selected type of user in the registration form? what I want is if the selected type of user is a student then I want to automatically create it in the student model after being registered not just in the User model. how to achieve that?

[image]

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_admin = models.BooleanField('Is admin', default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField('Is teacher', default=False)
    is_student = models.BooleanField('Is student', default=False)

class Student(models.Model):

    GENDER = (
        ('1', 'Male'),
        ('2', 'Female')
    )

    STATUS = (
        ('1', 'Ongoing'),
        ('2', 'On Probition'),
        ('3', 'NA')
    )

    name = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    id_number = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=GENDER, blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey(
        Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    year_level = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS, default='3')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

forms.py

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )
    email = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        # model = Profile
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',
                  'is_admin', 'is_teacher', 'is_student')
```

I think the logic should be added here in views.py but I don't know how to do it.

views.py

```
def register(request):
    msg = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            msg = 'user created'
            return redirect('login_view')
        else:
            msg = 'form is not valid'
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'register/register.html', {'form': form, 'msg': msg})
```

Comment: You'd need another form after this one to allow them to provide additional information required for that model, such as `name` for `Teacher` and `Gender` for `Student`.

Comment: @Lewis, so how to do it?

Comment: I would suggest you use [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/) that will allow you to perform operations as soon as a certain event occurs (for instance a new user, the action will depend on the type) (ensure, as mentioned @Lewis, that you have all required information - you might need to update your form accordingly)

Comment: @Christophe, how to know that the user that I'm going to register is a student, teacher, or admin?

Comment: Thanks to the option he will whose, it's part of the form, you might think about that globally and build your models accordingly. As a first sight, I would say you would need an addition attribute with 3 choices, but it might be possible to send the value from your posted form data to Signal (to be honest, I used it once on a very simple way, I know it's quite powerful for this stuff)

Comment: thank you, I got it now.